# WCF as a Data Service for html pages. jQuery ajax function.

Tags: post, put

**The get working fine but the get by id using POST or PUT is returning Error 404.**

**WCF DataService.svc**

Public Function GetHealthcare(ByVal CategoryId As String) As vwHealthcare Implements IDataService.GetHealthcare
        Dim nSubject As New vwHealthcare

```
    Dim context As DataClasses1DataContext = New DataClasses1DataContext()
    'Check if exists
    Dim res = From b In context.vwHealthcares Where b.CategoryId = CategoryId
              Select b
    Dim uList As List(Of vwHealthcare) = res.ToList()

    Return res
End Function
```

**IDataService**

```
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="GetHealthcareByCategoryId/{CategoryId}")>
<OperationContract()>
Function GetHealthcare(ByVal CategoryId As String) As vwHealthcare
```

**My Client Html :**

```
        // Urls to access the WCF Rest service methods


        var urlsource ;

       urlsource = "http://localhost/ehealthservice/DataService.svc/";
        var varType;
        var varUrl;
        var method;
        var varData;
        var varContentType;
        var varDataType;
        var varProcessData;

        //Generic function to call AXMX/WCF  Service
        function CallServiceC() {
            debugger;
            var categoryid = getQueryStringValue('CategoryId');

            var oData;

            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                url: varUrl, // Location of the service
                data: oData, //Data sent to server

                contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: varDataType,
                timeout: 2000,

                success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call

                    debugger;
                  // I want to get here





                            return html;

                        }

                },
                error: ServiceFailedC// When Service call fails
            });


        }


        function ServiceFailedC(result) {
            debugger;
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(result);

            alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
            varType = null; varUrl = null; varData = null; varContentType = null; varDataType = null; varProcessData = null;
        }


        function GetHealthcareByCategory() {
            debugger;

           varType = "POST";
           varUrl = urlsource + "GetHealthcareByCategoryId/1";

            varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            varDataType = "jsonp";
            varProcessData = false;
            method = "GetHealthcare";

            CallServiceC();
        }

        function getQueryStringValue(key) {
            debugger;
            return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
        };
        $(document).ready(

    function () {




        GetHealthcareByCategory();
    }

    );
```

**Note :**
I have tried many approach still the same 404 error. I have enabled the read/write permission on the folder too. This sample is following Pranya example with link [enter link description here](https://pranayamr.blogspot.com.ng/2011/03/rest.html?showComment=1487417235527#c6894823838335676205) and I still get Error 404 please any dev in the house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after days of searching and trying. Have to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) by adding adding it in the begin_Request of the Global.asax and clean up the web config. The link to the solution is here [Enable CORS In WCF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845474/Enabling-CORS-in-WCF.)

Note: I got away with it in the Get by using jsonp but the POST , PUT and DELETE could not go.
Thanks a lot.